# 2 Mail Server with same domain

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I am seeking an explanation. I want to setup a mail server with domain `aaa.com` in town A and another mail server with same domain `aaa.com` in town B. Each mail server in each town has their users (unique user which mean it won't exists in both server, just one of them). So what should i do to achieve this setup in order to let all the users in both server to be able to send and receive email without any problem. So i mean lets say i have user joe in town A and john in town B, and send an email from yahoo or gmail to both of them, and my mail will reach to them no matter which town they are in.

Note : I have a fully working email server with modoba.

Comment: If your email server supports SMTP namespace sharing then this should be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a full list of users on both systems.

On each system you configure the mailserver to accept mail for the domain and configure each user that relies on the other server as a forward (in postfix you can achieve this with virtual_alias_table).

However, there are many pitfalls and this is nothing you want to support in the long run.
I guess the smarter variant is to do the following:
Set up two SMTP servers (e.g. postfix, exim, whatever) with full knowledge of all users and set up two POP/IMAP servers that recieve mail via LMTP over TCP.
On each SMTP server you add a per-user rule that forwards mail to the correct LMTP destination.

This way both SMTP servers will accept mail for all users and forward the mail to the POP/IMAP-Server where the user's mailbox resides.

Comment: We would need to set the MX record to point to a DNS record that has two A records, one each for the SMTP servers as well.

Comment: You will need to set two MX records with the same priority. One for each server.

Comment: does MX record in DNS level can do the trick? i mean i will setup another MX to town B ip address with lower priority, so when it fails deliver to town A, it will go to town B? am i correct?

Answer (score 1):

Use Microsoft Exchange or a similar high end system.

See, SMTP is not designed to work like this - so you can not do it on an SMTP level. What you can do is use an enterprise level email system (because it is those that basically need it) that, while having front ends "somewhere" can handle distributing the mailboxes to separate servers (which can then be at different locations). And they can do so nicely, without all the config pain of a do it yourself solution, including moving mailboxes transparently.

Most of the time - unless you run enterprise grad users sending 150mb attachments in their emails - the question, though, is "why bother". Just put an email server somewhere. So, really, unless you have a very special case - you totally try to optimize the lease resource intensive protocol on your network.

Comment: This is an option *if* and only if you already have a common Active Directory forest deployed at both sites. Otherwise you'll end up deploying multi-site Active Directory and Exchange which is both quite complex.

Comment: Well, multi site AD is actually more on the trivial side, you know.

Comment: If you already know AD this is true. But I wouldn't dare settings this up unless you have at least some expierience doing this. You need to get DNS, site-selection and replication right which isn't trivial if you're doing it for the first time. Also if you already have two domains (one at each site) and you need to merge them or put them into a common forest this is not what I'd call "trivial". And btw. Exchange means $$$ :)

Comment: Actually, we have around 100 users in town B that may send/receive over 50MB of attachment. the other reason is that the IT guy in town A do not want to do the extra job like virtual alias, so i have to find a solution (town A is HQ). And how does those big company like Google And Yahoo do to their server, is it just they store all the user into a single server? i guess they are not. And how about the MX record things, can i assign another MX record to the IP of town B with lower priority? So when it fails to deliver to town B, it will seek for another MX? sorry for ignorance.

Comment: Well, they use an enterprise grade system. Microsoft Exchange does that without any sweat - including moving mailboxes when people move. Setting this up myself. SMTP does not handle it, you must handle it on a lower level.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is impossible. Plain and simple: SMTP was not designed to function like this. Mail routing is performed using MX records, which are created on a domain basis, not user basis.

That said, you *could* have foo.example.com at one town and bar.example.com at another town, each with their own users.

Comment: thats mean, i can go to DNS level and setup the MX record? Add another MX record that point to Town B, and when it fails to deliver to town A, it will goes to town B, and if both fails, it will bounce back to sender? is it right?

Comment: No, that's not how SMTP works.

Comment: so how is the gmail stuff works? are the users store in a single server while other MX is just a backup?

Answer (score 0):

As [Andreas](https://serverfault.com/users/414529/andreas-rogge) said, I think you can create such a setup without doing anything weird.

You make each server, at each location, have their own sub domain (`twa.aaa.com` for the server in Town A, `twb.aaa.com` for the one in Town B, etc.) and then have a master list of canonical names, that is in sync in all locations, that route between servers.

Joe and John can provide others with their canonical address `joe@aaa.com` and `john@aaa.com`. Internally, the mailbox for Joe is `joe@twa.aaa.com` and the same for John, `john@twb.aaa.com`. Output filters can rewrite their address, so any outgoing email they send will appear to the receiver as coming from canonical @aaa.com addresses.

There are several ways to handle email ingress:

- You can have a single MX server for all locations that dutifully forwards to the appropriate final storage (here you keep the canonical list in a single place),
- or have all locations act as MX server for its domain and also the canonical domain (here you have to keep in-sync copies of the canonical list, but have some sort of muti-zone high availability):

  Basically, all servers accept email for *@aaa.com, have local email delivery for their own *@twX.aaa.com and any other accepted email is forwarded using a table, like `transport_maps` in `postfix`. All modern MTAs have some sort of option for this.

Please note that all these setups can become complex to administer, and sometimes not bandwidth efficient (email for Town B is received in twa.aaa.com server because that is first MX record the sender received, and has to be relayed to twb.aaa.com for deliver) but that can certainly work.

Of course, existing email products handle this multi-server, multi-mailbox with nice UI interfaces and simplified administration.

You can get an idea of what I am proposing [with this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/107513/how-do-i-manage-multiple-mail-store-servers).

An unrelated nostalgic note: Done something like that using the venerable (and awfully complex to maintain) `sendmail` rulesets back in the 90's, using UUCP to connect some remotes offices by phone. 12k users.